# Flutter - How to add element inside nested Map?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add elements in a map which is already a value of a key inside another Map. I need to add element inside **answers** map.

```
Map myMap = {

'name' : 'Tom',

'answers' : {
    1 : 'correct',
    2 : 'wrong'
   }
}
```

I have a list of elements and if my condition passes then add that element inside **answers** map as (element : 'correct') and if it fails then (element : 'wrong').

To add element inside map based on condition below code works absolutely fine.

```
myMap.addIf(condition, element, 'correct')
myMap.addIf(!condition, element, 'wrong')
```

But if I use same logic for adding elements inside answers map it is giving below error.

```
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' has no instance method 'addIf'.
Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:0
Tried calling: addIf(false, 1, "correct"))
```

**As a alternate solution I write below code and it is working fine. But is there any way to add element in answers map?**

```
Map otherMap = {};
otherMap.addIf(condition, element, 'correct')

//assigning complete map as a value to answers key

myMap['answers'] = otherMap;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `cast` as shown below:

```
(myMap['answers'] as Map).addIf(condition, element, 'correct')
```